# Rabbitmq channel error on connection

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I have working srv0 with Application normally connected to rabbitmq

I've cloned srv0 to srv1 just ip chanded via customization(for test purposes)

Now Client application on srv1 can't connect to rabbit(Catalina.out):

`Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'wrs-checklist-delete' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)`

/var/log/rabbitmq/*.log answers

`=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Nov-2016::17:54:19 ===
Channel error on connection <0.344.0> (127.0.0.1:16899 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest'), channel 1:
{amqp_error,not_found,"no queue 'wrs-checklist-delete' in vhost '/'",
            'queue.declare'}`

checked:

- $HOSTNAME return host of srv1

Where should I start to realize the problem?

Comment: Please confirm rabbitmq on srv1 is running (`ps aux`) and listening on localhost (`netstat -a`).

Comment: sorry 5672 is up as well
`netstat -lntu
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::5672                     :::*                        LISTEN
`

Comment: did you start the queue ? I think there was a command to list all active queues, use that to check pls

Comment: ques are empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did't have queues, `./rabbitmqadmin list queues` returned ~connect error

I've stopped rabbit-server and deleted `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`

Then started rabbit-server and it recreated `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia`

after that created queues:

`./rabbitmqadmin declare exchange --vhost=/ name=queuename -create type=direct
./rabbitmqadmin declare queue --vhost=/ name=
./rabbitmqadmin --vhost=/ declare binding source="queuename" destination_type="queue" destination="queuename"`

and thats OK now